# Where can I get NPM package information from a Github Repository?

Tags: powershell, github, npm

I want to be able to get a few information about NPM packages in a Javascript based repository on Github.

I want to believe I can see them from the package.json file the repositories.

Please any help or guideline on this?.

I will like to extract the needed information using powershell from the file.

Comment: I am not very sure I understand your question? You need to parse `package.json` files? Or you need to query the NPM database?

Comment: I would prefer to parse the package.json files to get the npm packages that are created

Answer (score 1):

- Determine the URL for the *raw content* of the `package.json` file of interest:

  - E.g., for the [`json5` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5), click on the `Repository` link to go to the [associated GitHub repository](https://github.com/json5/json5), navigate to the [`package.json`](https://github.com/json5/json5/blob/master/package.json) file and click on the `Raw` button to get the [raw URL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json5/json5/master/package.json).
- Then use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) with the raw URL to retrieve and parse the content of the package's `package.json` file into an object whose properties you can access (the for-display output below shows the properties in the left column, and their values to the right - note the `dependencies` / `devDependencies` properties denoting what other packages the package at hand depends on at runtime / design time):

```
PS> Invoke-RestMethod https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json5/json5/master/package.json

name            : json5
version         : 2.2.0
description     : JSON for humans.
main            : lib/index.js
module          : dist/index.mjs
bin             : lib/cli.js
browser         : dist/index.js
types           : lib/index.d.ts
files           : {lib/, dist/}
engines         : @{node=>=6}
scripts         : @{build=rollup -c; build-package=node build/package.js; build-unicode=node build/unicode.js; coverage=tap --coverage-report html test; lint=eslint --fix .; prepublishOnly=npm run production; preversion=npm run production; production=npm run lint && npm test && npm run build; test=tap -Rspec --100 test; version=npm run build-package && git add package.json5}
repository      : @{type=git; url=git+https://github.com/json5/json5.git}
keywords        : {json, json5, es5, es2015…}
author          : Aseem Kishore <aseem.kishore@gmail.com>
contributors    : {Max Nanasy <max.nanasy@gmail.com>, Andrew Eisenberg <andrew@eisenberg.as>, Jordan Tucker <jordanbtucker@gmail.com>}
license         : MIT
bugs            : @{url=https://github.com/json5/json5/issues}
homepage        : http://json5.org/
dependencies    : @{minimist=^1.2.5}
devDependencies : @{core-js=^2.6.5; eslint=^5.15.3; eslint-config-standard=^12.0.0; eslint-plugin-import=^2.16.0; eslint-plugin-node=^8.0.1; eslint-plugin-promise=^4.0.1; eslint-plugin-standard=^4.0.0; regenerate=^1.4.0; rollup=^0.64.1; rollup-plugin-buble=^0.19.6; rollup-plugin-commonjs=^9.2.1; rollup-plugin-node-resolve=^3.4.0; rollup-plugin-terser=^1.0.1; sinon=^6.3.5; tap=^12.6.0; unicode-10.0.0=^0.7.5}
```

**Deriving the URLs *programmatically*:**

```
# Package name.
$npmPackageName = 'json5'

# Derive the package's npm registry URL
$npmUrl = "https://www.npmjs.com/package/$npmPackageName"

# Derive the associated API URL
$npmApiUrl = $npmUrl -replace '(?<=/)www(?=.)', 'replicate' -replace '/package'

# Derive the source-code repository URL
$repoUrl = Invoke-RestMethod $npmApiUrl |
  ForEach-Object { $_.repository.url.Substring($_.repository.type.Length+1) }

# Assuming the source-code repository is a GitHub URL, 
# derive the *raw* URL from it, from which files can be downloaded
# as-is. 
$rawGitHubUrl= 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/' + ($repoUrl -replace '\.git$' -replace '^https://github\.com/')

# Derive the raw URL for the package.json file.
$rawPackageJsonUrl = "$rawGitHubUrl/master/package.json"

# Parse the package.json file's JSON content into an object
$objectFromPackageJson = Invoke-RestMethod $rawPackageJsonUrl

# Output an example property.
$objectFromPackageJson.dependencies
```

Comment: so if I check the output of the Raw, where are the packages located?. and is this the same for all output ?

Comment: @CalebAdepoju, I don't fully understand your question, but see if my update helps.